# Uncaught ReferenceError: sendMessage is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Basically I was developing a chatApp using ws module and facing some issue on the frontend side regarding the the code not able to get a function in its scope.
**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Real-Time Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="chat-window" class="chat-box"></div>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="Type your message...">
      <!-- Corrected onclick syntax -->
      <button id="send-btn">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Include client.js script -->
  <script src="client.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
      // Corrected event listener registration without invoking the function
      sendButton.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the html code I am using on the frontend
**style.css**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #fffdd0; /* Light yellow background */
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Aligns content horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* Aligns content vertically */
    height: 100vh; /* Full viewport height */
  }
  
  .container {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .chat-box {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .input-container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #message-input {
    flex: 1; /* Takes remaining space */
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  button {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #007bff; /* Blue button color */
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  /* Message bubble styling */
  .message-bubble {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  
  .message-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end; /* Aligns sent messages to the right */
  }
```

this is styles.css code which is used with html code for better view.
**client.js**

```
// client.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');
  const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

  // Event handler for incoming messages
  ws.onmessage = event => {
    const messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const { message, sender } = messageData;

    if (sender !== 'self') {
      appendMessage(message);
    }
  };

  // Function to send a message
  function sendMessage() {
    const message = messageInput.value.trim();
    if (message !== '') {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ message }));
      messageInput.value = '';
    }
  }

  // Function to append a message to the chat window
  function appendMessage(message) {
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
    messageElement.textContent = message;
    messageElement.classList.add('message-bubble');
    chatWindow.appendChild(messageElement);
    chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;
  }
});
```

These were all components of the frontend and the error it is giving as soon as we click the send button is
`Uncaught ReferenceError: sendMessage is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):24:44)`

Comment: @freedomn-m If I'll move the that function out of DOMContentLoaded then how will I access the `messageInput` variable ?

Comment: @freedomn-m still the same error. I think we have to change in the code in script tags on html page. The way it is called would be changed?

Comment: okay So what changes should I make I am getting blank in this. @freedomn-m

Comment: In this ( jsfiddle.net/cs4ahjub/2) solution chatWindow is not defined anywhere. What about that ?@freedomn-m